Delete part of plain in 3Th layer of altium
I am trying to split the GND and power inside the 2nd and 3rd layers, however, there is some dead copper that I can not delete, could you pls tell me how? this picture below is a part of Plain I want to delete


This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

@ChrisKnudsen No it won't, again! It keeps saying, the forum is unavailable! so check your link before pasting the same comment over and over again

@Ergophobia forum.live.altium.com seems to be working as of 2024/04/27 (I just checked from another computer). Perhaps it was down when you last tried? Maybe you or your location is blacklisted? I am not affiliated with Altium in any way. However, EESE does tend to get flooded with Altium issues every so often, and many seem to be not aware of the Altium forum is the best resource for such questions.

If it's a negative layer, then you need to split the planes with a trace on that layer. You can also use planes to fill in dead copper on a negative layer.
If it's a polygon, you need to select it and delete it. It looks like it's a polygon so you should able to delete it, make sure it isn't locked.
If you want to get rid of a island, click on the plane and then select remove dead copper and increase the area until it goes away.

thanks , it's a plain split, i split the plains using line, i can not delete nor say remove dead copper since it's not a polygon

Right, if you have dead copper fill it in with a plane on the same layer

i am sorry , i dont get it , how ?

Select the layer, push the draw plane button, draw the polygon fill on the layer in the area of the dead copper
